# How to insert an entity with autoincremented field in .net core without messing with SQL Server 'Identity_insert on'?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, identity

What would be the best practice for storing some entity in a SQL Server database, when I have an `Id` property which is autoincremented (identity)?

This is for a .NET Core application, using Entity Framework Core. I suppose that I could just create some new entity without the identity `id`, and move the values of my old entity to my new entity the store it in the `.Add` method of my current context, or execute a command for enable the 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON', but both of those approaches looks messy, I'm guessing that there is a cleaner way to achieve this.

```cs
//user has autoincremented property
public IEnumerable<User> SaveUser(User user)
{
     context.add(user);
     context.SaveChanges(); // Exception Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table
}
```

I expect to get to do it in a way that I could reuse it in the whole application, because if my entities keep increasing in size, I would have to write this messy code all around.

Comment: The only reason to have `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` is to be able to **specify** those identity values yourself. So if that option is on, you **must** supply a suitable value for `Id` yourself - just like for any other property. The question really is: ***WHY*** is `IDENTITY_INSERT` on when you seem to struggle with providing a suitable value?? What's the reason it's been turned on????

Comment: @marc_s My question was more about in the scenario that i might want to duplicate an entity, is there any way to clone my entity and before inserting my copied entity in the database, specify through code 'ok database, i know my copied entity has the same 'ID' value that one that is currently stored in the db, please dont map at this point the property ID because i know it will conflict with you' i don't know if i'm making myself clear

Answer (score 0):

To start with, I would like to ask/point at your model class. Not sure how you are having your EF on .net core, but if you are to have a model (be it code first or model first),

lets just say, your Entity model looks similar to below:

```
User
{
    UserId (as int),
    UserName (as string),
    BirthDate (as date)
}
```

You can achieve the identity insert by below approach:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId {get;set;}

    public string UserName {get;set;}

    public DateTime BirthDate {get;set;}
}
```

Please explore and learn about Code first approach, Modelling your data, repository patterns (may be the ideal in my perspective but depends on case or could be a good learning) and see to the attributes, annotations decorations for EF models.

To explain on what actually drives the auto identity by the above annotations,

1. Identity generation (auto identity prop)

   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

is the driving factor, also depends on the data type. some data types may need additional param configurations. Explore when you try out on your solution. For example, you can use Guid data type and see how it turns out in your Db.

2. primary key or key attr

   [Key]

is as simple to denote as the primary key field in the model/entity structure. This may not be helping or running the auto identity but, i am explaining about this on why i added this attribute in my sample code above.

Comment: I'm currently using fluent API, and aplying repository pattern, my question was more about in the scenario that i might want to duplicate an entity, is there any way to clone my entity and before inserting my copied entity in the database, specify through code 'ok database, i know my copied entity has the same 'ID' value that one that is currently stored in the db, please dont map at this point the property ID because i know it will conflict with you' i don't know if i'm making myself clear

Comment: Why do you want to do that? copying your entity? May be, if you explain in detail of what you are trying to do, we can solve without duplicating the entity. Ideally, you should avoid copying the entity before moving to database. Like if you trying to have your model stored in the Db, i assume you are trying like viewModel to dataModel?